# how to make a link to a S3 file download rather then display

Tags: amazon-s3

If I have a file stored on amazon S3 and I want it to download when the user clicks on it normally, how can I accomplish that?

I found some information on setting the content disposition(?) but I can't find anything actually providing instructions on how to do so.

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: no framework ... HTML ... an anchor. `<a href='amazon.link'>Open Download Dialog</a>`

Comment: `content-disposition` has to be set server side. I've never used S3, but is there an option when you upload to it to set `Content-Disposition` to `attachment`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can select file > properties > meta-data and add the content-disposition header as an option there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check **Content-Disponsition** in your File S3 or when upload the file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it by using setContentDisposition in sdk

In java

```
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename=...");
```

By this when a user clicks on the link file will be downloaded